# Is question about user interface optimization on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

I have made dialog box that hosts a lot of various controls ( around 50 ) using C++ and raw WinAPI.

Although my application works, I still wish to somehow reduce the number of controls I use in a dialog box. I wish to ask on User Experience for help, so I first wanted to check here if this type of question is on topic?

If it isn't can you suggest me SE network that could help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is something like:

> I've built {this dialog box}, how can I improve it?

Then no, that's not really on topic. That's really just a review of your interface, so there is no 'correct' answer to such a question. You're better off posting to somewhere like http://fivesecondtest.com/ instead.

However, if your question is more like:

> I have buttons for 'save', 'save and exit', 'cancel', 'continue' and 'save and continue' and users are telling me that it is too confusing, is there a suitable alternative to providing all these options?

Then that is more suited. It's a question that can be answered in a more-or-less 'correct' fashion. A good answer will solve your situation and - more importantly - provide some use to other visitors to the site.

Think of stack exchange as a big repository (or encyclopeadia) of useful questions and their appropriate answers - a site people can come to to read in order to find the answer to a question they are pretty sure others must have asked at some point in time.

Providing a consultancy service for reviewing individual people websites / apps doesn't really fit into that category. But solving specific problems does.

Comment: My question tends towards your first point, but it can be phrased in such a way that concrete answer can be given. The reason I have so many controls is that dialog box collects input for database and number of tables and fields is just to large. Users didn't complain but I dislike my own design, and thus seek *a suitable alternative to providing all these options* as you've mentioned.

Comment: Providing you have a specific problem that needs solving, and is more than just 'make this look a bit better and I'll see if I like your suggestion' then it's probably on topic. But it has to be an answerable question based on an actual problem that you have/

Comment: I think I will give it a try, based on your comments/answer as I do believe community can help me out. Thank you.