# Are questions about UI friendliness on topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

I currently am making a UI menu for people, but am a total leek in user friendliness. Would a question about increasing the user friendliness of a UI be on topic ? I already found [Is question about user interface optimization on topic?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/is-question-about-user-interface-optimization-on-topic) But did not find the answer satisfiable for my question.

Comment: Why is the answer there not satisfying to you?

Comment: @jonW it is not clear to me wether it is on topic or not after reading it.

Comment: That's because it's going to depend on the type of question you are going to ask. We can't say all 'User Friendlyness' questions are on-topic, nor can we say none of them are. It all depends on the question itself. If it's a question with a specific problem that needs solving then it's probably OK, but if it's just a question asking us to improve the user-friendlyness without anything qualifying what is wrong then it's unlikely to be a suitable question for the site.

Comment: @jonW okay thats clear enough